# Program to make the textfile to be lowercase

Tags: edit

Goal:
I have a big text (txt) file that is about 70 mb.

I need to make the whole content to be lowercase.

Program:
Do you know any solution / program that is enable to make the whole content to be lowercase or small text and no big letter?

I tried to find a simple solution but it doesn't go so well.

Info:
*This will be used for a who do not have the skills of software programming.
*The process should only take place in your local computer.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: It is only for windows 10 no unix in this context

Answer (score 1):

In your case [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do the work. Open the file in the editor, Ctrl+A (to select all the file), Ctrl+U (to convert to lowercase) and save the file. I just test it with 300MB file, load take ~3 sec, select entire file also ~3 sec, convert to lowercase around 15 sec.

You can use also one terminal emulator [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), open new shell, navigate (with UNIX commands) to the file then execute:

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' input_file >output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in PowerShell:

```
$x = "FullyQualifiedPathOfFile.txt"
(Get-Content -Path $x).ToLower() | Set-Content -Path $x
```